# Trying do_shortcode inside template file but need php inside do_shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

i have a php template for a posts archive and that is the part

```
<h3 class="entry-title mh-posts-grid-title">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark">   
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a>
</h3>
```

Now i want to use this inside a shortcode and i tried it only with the part of the_title();

I tried several solutions i found here. When i try it with simple html instead of the_title() it works, but as soon as i try it with the_title i get errors or the title doesn't appear.   I need enclosing shortcodes

What i tried

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[um_loggedin] $the_title [/um_loggedin]' );?
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[um_loggedin] $the_title() [/um_loggedin]' );?
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[um_loggedin] $the_title(); [/um_loggedin]' );?
```

Same without $

Thanks for any help :(

Comment: Start with some basics: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

Now i have found the solution myself

```
echo do_shortcode('[um_loggedin]'.get_the_title().' [/um_loggedin]');
```